# EditText showing in a weird way below Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

I have two EditText in my layout. The problem is that it is being shown in a weird way in different Android Versions.
This is how it is showing in **Android 4.1.1 Jellybean(Intex Aqua Wonder)**  OR anything below Lollipop

[image: IMAGE 1]

And this is how it is being shown in **Android 5.1 Lollipop(Moto E2)**

[image: IMAGE 2]

This is my layout file
ID of the edittext are edt_title and edt_desc(For searching).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ppv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/logo_background"
tools:context="in.net.spectrum.frankstrade.SellActivity_2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:title="@string/app_name"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#F7F7F7"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_camera"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/camera" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imv_gallery"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/gallery" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroller"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv1"
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo1"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />


                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv2"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo2"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress2"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv3"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo3"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress3"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv4"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo4"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                            <ProgressBar
                                android:id="@+id/progress4"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="30dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                                android:indeterminate="true" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:id="@+id/img_cv5"
                                android:layout_width="150dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:background="@color/colorCardView"
                                android:visibility="gone">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_photo5"
                                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:background="@drawable/border" />

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progress5"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                            android:indeterminate="true" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add upto 5 images, each of max size 4 MB" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorCardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/cardView_padding">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txt_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:text="Select Category : "
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btn_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                            android:text="Select Category" />

                        <Spinner
                            android:id="@+id/sp_category"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorCardView">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/cardView_padding">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/txt_CharacterCounter"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"/>
                        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/input_layout_title"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/edt_title"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Title(maximum 100 characters)*"
                                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                                android:maxLength="100"
                                android:singleLine="true" />
                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edt_desc"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:hint="Description(maximum 5000 characters)*"
                            android:singleLine="true" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cb_stockimage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add this image you own to stock image"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dummy"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="dummy"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next_sa2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_corners"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Gradle File :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.net.spectrum.frankstrade"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'


compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
//compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'

/* compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'*/

//compile files('libs/library.jar')
compile project(':android_process_button_library')
//compile project(':library_smooth_progress_bar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
//compile project(':library_materialEditText')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.0.jar')
//compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.3'
compile project(':multipleimageselect')



}
```

Apparently every edittext in my app is showing this way in Android 4.1.1 Jellybean. How can i solve this problem.....?
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to set a background image ?

Comment: Heyy.. what is the version of Studio you are using ? My colleague, too, faced this problem. I think there is something wrong with new version Android Studio.

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

in your build.gradle (Project:XXXX)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create style for `EditText`

```
<style name="edt_text" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
  <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/edt_color_gray</item>
  <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/edt_hintColor</item>
  <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
  <item name="android:inputType">textCapSentences</item>
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
  <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/grey</item>
</style>
```

Now use this style in your xml layout file

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edt_product"
  style="@style/edt_text"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:text=""
  android:textColor="#616161" 
/>
```

Comment: use this android:background="@null"

Comment: I did this, but then i lost the underline of the edittext. Any workaround that...?

Comment: create drawable file for bottom line and set as background 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>